# ExtJs dolayout on panel

Tags: extjs, layout, grid, panel

I have a grid inside the panel. Initially i will render the grid to the panel when the application is loaded and on specific user operation (say click on grid:2) i will hide the grid inside panel using hide(). When the grid is hided i will display a message in panel using panel.update(html). Now again on specific user operation (say click on grid:3) i need to show the grid inside panel. i tried with grid.show(), grid.setvisible() and panel.doLayout() but none work out. Below is the sample code,

```
    if (condition1){
      panelGrid.setVisible(false);
      panel.update("htmltext");
    } else {
      panel.doLayout();
      panelGrid.setVisible(true);
    }
```

This works fine in firefox. But in IE8 it does not work and displays a error message "Unspecified error in ext-base.js"

Any one has any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I figured the logic myself.

I have used add() instead of panel.update().

```
if (condition1){
  panelGrid.setVisible(false);
  panel.remove('sample', true);
  panel.add(
   {
     id: 'sample'
     html:'htmltext'
   });
} else {
  panel.remove('sample', true);
  panelGrid.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You override panel's HTML when doing `panel.update`, so the grid no longer existing.

Comment: Why this occurs only in IE alone?
is there any way i can achieve this? i cannot give html property for panel as some variables used inside html are not in scope of the panel

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I figured myself and posted the answer here